# Mirror screen MacBook late-2013 to iMac late-2015

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt-display, mirroring

I would like to mirror my MacBook late-2013 (Big Sur 11.7) screen to my iMac late-2015 (Monterey 12.6) screen.

I am able to use Screen Sharing but cannot expand the MacBook screen to full width on the iMac and use the full iMac screen, furthermore, it is slow.

This <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> solution does not work. What other options do I have, if any?

Comment: There is no other easy solution. iMacs after 2014 don’t support [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), i.e. `Cmd` +`F2`.  If you really need resolve this, you may want to look into a 3rd party solution such as [luna display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/).

Comment: did anyone tried with a HDMI adaptor?